# Is there a way to search questions you/me have upvoted?

Tags: feature-request, search

Is there a way to search questions that a specific user (me) has upvoted? I looked at the advanced ninja search options, however I didn't see anything, maybe I'm just missing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  It's not even available via the data dump.

However, the system does display them when you visit the question, so in theory you could build a screen scraper that gathers the information for you.

But there's no easy way.

If you think you want to refer to a question you've upvoted, consider marking it as a favorite by clicking the little start below the question voting spot.